# Can't set datasource programmatically, getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, datasource

I'm trying to set datasource for my table view programmatically, I have a class which I created and it implements (I don't know if implements is the right word for it, new to OC, I come from Java) the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

`@interface PlaylistController : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`

in my `ViewController` in the `viewDidLoad` method I try to assign the datasource, but I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

`[playlistView setDataSource:[[PlaylistController alloc] initWithPlaylist:playlist]];`

And I don't know why?

From reading here (SO) I understand that it either a casting problem (but I do implement the needed protocol), or memory management problem (but I'm using ARC, not touching release at all)

Comment: `I'm trying to set datasource programatically to my table view` HOW?? It should be I'm trying to set datasource programatically **of** my table view

Comment: You're right, fixed it :)

Comment: Danger! `@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDataSource> dataSource` (note the `assign`)!

Comment: Anyway, you need to post a stacktrace.

Comment: @trojanfoe: is this `[playlistView setDataSource:[[PlaylistController alloc] initWithPlaylist:playlist]];` correct?

Comment: @trojanfoe Can you please elaborate about this, I'm just starting with OC, and, please, do it in an answer so I could accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Well you don't say if you are using ARC or MRR, and this is not the problem you are immediately facing, but if you're using ARC then setting the datasource like that won't retain it (given the property is `assign`) so it will disappear almost immediately.  You need to allocate it to instance variable of the view controller and then set it as the data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
[playlistView setDataSource:[[PlaylistController alloc] initWithPlaylist:playlist]];
```

Use

```
[playlistView setDataSource:self];
```

Reason:

You tried to set DataSource to an instance that is in `autorelease`. It gets released and you get the Error.

You should set the dataSource to `self`, so that it points to the current instance of the class.

Comment: And what should I do if I want to assign it to a different class' instance?

Comment: create a property of type strong and then assign it as datasource.

Comment: What is the difference between giving it the property of strong vs. assign as suggested by trojanfoe ?

Comment: `strong` in ARC means `retain` it will be there unless owner releases it as compared to `assign` or `weak`.

Comment: So, If I get this right, giving it the property of assign, will be wrong. Because ARC will be able to release it while the object where it was assigned is still in use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a UITableView object set anywhere.

Make sure you have an IBOutlet created and linked to a UITableView in your Nib file.

```
@interface PlaylistController : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;

@end

Then in your viewDidLoad you can do:

[tableView setDataSource:self]
```

Comment: Doing this means setting the current context instance (`ViewController`) to be the datasource, I don't want that

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you however extend UITableViewController instead of just NSObject, you won't need to declare a UITableView in your .h file.